# Cancel alarm with notification android when app is closed

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have implemented a reminder system into my application which uses the `AlarmManager` provided by android. I have initialized notifications to trigger, once the alarm sets off (when the app is open or closed) but i cannot seem to switch the alarm off in either state.

I cannot seem to find my answer anywhere. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show your current code for switching off the alarm?

Answer (score 0):

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, myIntent,                                

PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: does the Context in "Contect.ALARM_SERVICE" need to be the same as the context the alarm was created in or in the screen the user gets taken too when they click the notification?

Comment: Have you implemented the onDestroy() in your Service Class? Try to do it otherwise post your code to take a look on it